# ActiveRecord "lower(column_name)" is still case sensitive. (MySql2, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mysql2

I am using MySql2 in my Rails application. I am trying to make an activerecord query that returns all records that have specified fields containing a string. I have read that downcasing my input and then using `lower(column_name) LIKE 'string'` should do the trick, but **this does not appear to work**. My query is exactly as follows:

```
search = params[:search].to_s.downcase

@current_user.patients.where("lower(last_name) LIKE ? OR lower(first_name) LIKE ? OR lower(identifier) LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
```

Let's say I have a record with the last name "Abbott". When my search param is "Abb" or "bot", this record is returned. However, when the search param is "abb" or "Bot", nothing is returned. It appears that the query is **still case sensitive**??

I have looked all over and cannot seem to find an answer. I have read multiple times that `lower(column_name)` should work, but it does not.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you include a description of the table too (i.e. `DESCRIBE patients`)?

Comment: Do you have the SQL log that it generate?

Comment: @VincentB. the table schema looks like this: Patient(id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, identifier: binary, first_name: binary, last_name: binary, dob: binary, creator_id: integer, chrono_id: integer, most_recent_recording_created_at: datetime). 
Now that i look at it, could it be because they're binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was indeed because the fields were stored as binary values (thanks Vincent). By casting the binary fields as a CHARs, I was able to case-insensitively compare them:

`@current_user.patients.where("CAST(last_name AS CHAR) LIKE ? OR ...`